# Detect screen orientation change (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

How do I detect when screen orientation changes between portrait and landscape (iPhone/iPad, Swift 4)?

I am trying to set constraints of two container views so that one appears above the other when in portrait orientation but side by side when in landscape orientation (and update whenever the user changes orientation).

(I believe I can do this using a stackview in Storyboard - would love if someone would show me how - but I want to do it programmatically in this case.)

I think this will only work when the ViewController is first loaded but will not update the constraints if the orientation is subsequently changed between Portrait and Landscape.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Orientations {
        static let Portrait = "Portrait"
        static let Landscape = "Landscape"
        static let OtherOrientation = "OtherOrientation"
    }        
    var currentOrientation = Orientations.Portrait

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        setConstraints()
    }
    

    func setConstraints() {
       // pseudocode:
       if currentOrientation == Orientations.Portrait {
           setConstraintsPortrait()
           print("Portrait")
       else if currentOrientation == Orientations.Landscape {
           setConstraintsLandscape()
           print("Landscape")
       }
    }


    // any help on these would also be much appreciated!
    func setConstraintsPortrait() {
        //tbd
    }

    func setConstraintsLandscape() {
        //tbd
    }

}
```

So, I guess my questions are:

- how to detect the change from portrait to landscape
- how to act on the change
- any other help on setting those constraints - my first thoughts are the following:

```
// Portrait
childVCTop.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
childVCTop.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
childVCTop.view.heightAnchor.constraint(EqualToConstant: screenHeight / 2).isActive = true
childVCTop.view.widthAnchor.constraint(EqualToConstant: screenWidth / 2).isActive = true

childVCBottom.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
childVCBottom.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
childVCBottom.view.heightAnchor.constraint(EqualToConstant: screenHeight / 2).isActive = true
childVCBottom.view.widthAnchor.constraint(EqualToConstant: screenWidth / 2).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to detect the change from portrait to landscape

You can implement the following method given from UIViewController:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    // here you can react to the orientation change
}
```

> how to act on the change

Your idea of changing constraints based on orientation is a good start. I would recommend using a stackview and changing the axis on orientation, though, but thats a wild guess.

> any other help on setting those constraints - my first thoughts are the following

As I said, I would try using a stackview just to not have the hustle around constraints in code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to detect orientation changes for your logic with `UIApplication.didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` e.g.:

```swift
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onOrientationChange), name: UIApplication.didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, object: nil)
    ...
}

@objc func onOrientationChange(notification: Notification) {
    let isPortrait = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait
    ...
}
```